# JAVA Regex - find Substring between two delimiters - last occurrence of / and another pattern

Tags: java, regex, substring

While testing Azure Blob URLs I came across a situation where I need to extract the Blob file being uploaded. In following example:
    https://servername.windows.net/virtual/folder/IwantToFindThisFileName.AnyExtension?Azurekey=SASKeyDetails

So I want to find - between the last occurrence of **/** (which is after folder/) and first occurrence of **?** (which is ?AzureKey) - which would return  the fileName (which can of any extension).

Note: AzureKey is not a reserved word. It can be ?hg= or ?cn or ?asdf=   etc

Required Output is only  `IwantToFindThisFileName.AnyExtension`  , nothing else otherwise it will require further processing on the extracted sub-string

Comment: But the query was not just finding the last / and first ?. It was easy with  indexOf and lastIndexOf. But needed a pattern
this worked   (?=[^\/]+$).+(?=\?\w+=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work:

```
(?=[^\/]+$).+?(?=\?)
```

Not sure if/how to escape in `Java` (Rookie here). But maybe the general idea is correct? Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/tily10/2)

Comment: actually it should be (?=[^\/]+$).+(?=\?\w+=) to ensure that we have taken into account 
?anyword
as expected in the question. That was the whole point of specifying  ?AzureKey= in Note